# На плеймаркете в консоле разработчика ноль поддерживаемых устройств

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, playmarket

Не пойму в чем проблема, загружаю апк в консоль разработчика. Пишет, что 0 поддерживаемых устройств. До этого публиковал апк все нормально было, а это почему-то не проходит. Не могу понять почему.

gradle

```
    compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "kit.google"
            minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 6
            multiDexEnabled true
            versionName "0.0.6"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"


        }
```

manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".view.activitys.mainActivity.MainActivityImpl">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

данные с плей маркета http://take.ms/Gujuh

Comment: Скриншоты добавили?

Answer (score -1):

Возможно, Вы добавили что-то лишнее в Dependencies, у меня устройства появились только после удаления org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io , на работе моего приложения, это никак не сказалось.